# How long can a Corda flow be suspended for?

Tags: corda

In Corda, how long can a flow be suspended for? Is there a limit at the node or the network level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Corda does not impose a limit on how long a flow can be suspended.

However, we don't recommend that you suspend flows for long because checkpoint upgrade is only partially supported. If you refactor code that might be on the stack in a checkpoint you will get crashes and corruptions. You can still refactor functions that are not marked as `@Suspendable`, and make serialisation-compatible changes to data structures that are on the heap snapshot

With the current flow APIs (Corda V2), you can only suspend flows for P2P messages, so it isn't easy to sleep for long periods anyway. Over time this will become more of an issue as we make it possible to wait for additional kinds of events.